# Undefined Control Sequence for my 0-norm

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath, undefined

I'm new to latex and am using some stuff from a document my professor sent out.

I'm trying to define something in a paper I'm writing. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath,amsthm,enumitem,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,multicol,tikz,pgfplots,tkz- 
euclide,relsize,framed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{fontscale/.style = {font=\relsize{#1}}}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.750in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumii}.}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Important Definitions and Theorems}

\subsection{Definition [Sparsity]}
The \emph{sparsity} of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by 
\begin{equation}
\norm{x}_{0} = card{k \in {1, 2, . . . , n} : x_k \neq 0}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

However, when I run this I get an Undefined Control Sequence error and I'm not sure what that means or how to fix it, hence I have come for your merciful help. Thanks!

Comment: The undefined control sequence is `\norm`. Do *you* have any preference for how the norm of something should be denoted?

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're loading the `amssymb` package, there can be no excuse or justification for loading `latexsym` as well. Similarly, since you're loading the `graphicx` package, nothing but a high tolerance for code clutter can justify loading `graphics` as well.

Comment: If the template you're using comes straight from your professor, you may want to suggest to him/her that de-crufting the template that's being inflicted on the students should be made a very high priority.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. The only preference I have for how the norm of something is denoted is how it should normally look--something inside what looks like two absolute value bars with a subscript denoting the type of norm. Okay. I'll keep that in mind. What I am working on is literally the second document I've ever written in LaTex. To prevent confusion and to just get us started, my professor gave us all that intro stuff with the packages. I'll let him know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\norm` is not defined by default. A common way to define it is to use `mathtools` and `\DeclarPairedDelimiter`, so that `\norm` can be called

```latex
\norm{x}
\norm[\big]{x}
\norm[\Big]{x}
\norm[\bigg]{x}
\norm[\Bigg]{x}
\norm*{x}
```

where the calls with the optional argument manually set the size of the delimiter; the `*`-form uses automatically extensible delimiter (to be used sparingly).

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

% load here other needed packages
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}

% set up for the document
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\calclayout % <--- this is the proper way in amsart

% personal commands
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}

% theorem like environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Important Definitions and Theorems}

\begin{definition}[Sparsity]
The \emph{sparsity} of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by 
\begin{equation}
\norm{x}_{0} = \card\bigl\{k \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\} : x_k \neq 0\bigr\}
\end{equation}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- Instead of abusing `\subsection` I defined proper environments for theorems and definition (add the others you need).
- I also defined an operator name for the cardinality.
- The braces for delimiting the set definition should be `\{` and `\}`.
- Because of the nested sets, I used `\big` for the outer braces (it's optional).
- `...` should be `\dots`.
- Instead of guessing at the appropriate values for the page parameters, just set the desired text height and width, then issue `\calclayout` (a command proper of `amsart`) to set the others.

Comment: Weird that norm is not already defined in the package. Maybe it isn't weird, but mathematicians (especially analysts) use them all the time. Thanks for all the help though. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Adding this definition, based on \mathtools (an extension of `amsmath`) works fine.  I defined a `\znorm` command which stretches to the size of its argument in its starred version. Alternatively, you can fine-tune the size of the norm symbols using an optional argument one of `\big, \Big, \bigg, \Bigg`.

Unrelated: you don't have yo load `graphics` if you load `graphicx`: the latter does it for you. Similarly, needless to load `amsmath`if you load `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsthm,enumitem,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,multicol,tikz,pgfplots,tkz-euclide,relsize,framed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{fontscale/.style = {font=\relsize{#1}}}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.750in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumii}.}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\znorm[1]{}\lVert\rVert{_0}{#1}
\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}

\begin{document}

\section{Important Definitions and Theorems}

\subsection{Definition [Sparsity]}
The \emph{sparsity} of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\znorm{x}=\card\bigl\{k \in \{1, 2, . . . , n\} : x_k \neq 0\bigr\}\qquad \znorm*{\frac{x}{a}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: you're right. I focused  on the rest, so I  didn't notice it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Bernard!